# Does it make sense to write $(T - \lambda I)v$ if $T$ is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am reading [this](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~scanez/courses/334/notes/jordan-form.pdf) page to try to understand Jordan form. $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space, and until now $T$ has always represented an "operator", by which I guess they mean a linear transformation.

Towards the bottom of the first page they write $(T - \lambda I)v= 0$. Now I know that with any linear transformation $T:V \to V$ we can associate a matrix. However, that matrix is usually represented as $[T]_{B \leftarrow B}$.

Is $([T]_{B \leftarrow B} - \lambda I) [v]_B$  what they probably meant to write on the website, or does $(T - \lambda I)v$ have a meaning somehow when $T$ is just a linear transformation?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what they mean. It's the same as saying when you simply diagonalize a lineair transformation. You choose a basis, and the diagonalize it. (However, as your gut feeling probably tells you already, in the end it doesn't matter which basis you choose).

Comment: It is the linear transformation $(T-\lambda I)$ applied to the vector $v.$ Is the confusion about the $\lambda I$ part?

Comment: Not sure if this is your question, but $I$ typically refers to the identity operator on the space. That is, $Iv = v$ for all $v \in V$. It is also used to refer to the identity matrix, which is mildly confusing.

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah of course, got it. Yes I kept thinking of $I$ as the identity matrix.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah that was the confusion but I got it now, I kept thinking about $I$ as the identity matrix.

Comment: @TheoBendit Just to make sure I understand, could you please double check my understanding? $(T- \lambda I)v = (T- \lambda I)(v) = T(v) - (\lambda I)(v) = T(v) - \lambda (I(v)) = T(v) - \lambda v$? And then, for example, $(T - \lambda I)^2 (v) = (T - \lambda I) ( T(v) - \lambda v) = T(T(v)) -  \lambda T(v) - \lambda T(v) - \lambda^2 v$

Comment: @Ovi That's right.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks!

Comment: Probably you mean  $+\lambda^2 v$ instead of $-\lambda^2 v$  in the expression above.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Yes, thanks!